# What is an appropriate software for furniture design?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to master a software for furniture design but I don't know what's an appropriate and powerful solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are plenty of software available depend on your need and pocket

check these links

1. [Sketchlist](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http://www.sketchlist.com/&ei=faX4TerlN4WqrAffxPi1CA&usg=AFQjCNEKq8XrQJso9z2XrAF_Dvavd8ReZg) (*easy to learn and you might finish your design within the 14 day trial period. It also contains all the drawings and reports you will need to make the wardrobe.*)
2. [ecruso](http://en.ecrusoftware.com/)
3. [gama 3d](http://www.gamma3d.net/)
4. [Topic discussed on Software recommendation](http://boards.core77.com/viewtopic.php?t=9104)

wish  to see  you soon as successful furniture designer :) all the best

Answer (score 4):

Many furniture makers use Sketchup which is a free software that used to be owned by Google. There is a strong community with interest in the woodworking world. Sketchup has an easy to learn interface and will get you producing working designs pretty quickly. Most 3d software is time consuming to learn and expensive to acquire. Check out the forums at [sketchucation.com](http://sketchucation.com) to learn more.

Comment: Good of you to point out that more complex 3d software does indeed take long to master!

Answer (score 3):

AutoCAD for drafting, modeling and detailing.

3ds max for render with realistic materials.

Adobe photoshop for post production.

Comment: I recommend Maya over 3D Studio Max

Answer (score 2):

**Usability** is the key - possibly more than completness of functions.  Some design packages offer so much it's hard to grasp it all.  A 2D layout or design actually accomplished as Microsoft Word drawing or Paint image can be better than no design at all (sometimes :) )  One reviewer of CAD packages wrote in a woodworking magazine: "Basic test of a product is if I can draw a line.  Most of the times that test fails".  So answer the question"  "Can I actually use the software to accomplsih what I need?"

Comment: indeed, nice words.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, there is plenty of 3D software. I have on the other hand only seen it done with **Rhino 3D**. Probably because it can import many file types (screw templates, hinges), is **very quick in contructing** with somewhat simple shapes, can **combine surfaces and volume models** and adding dimensions is rather easy. All this is probably doable with other software too (especially AutoCAD) but it seems designers favor it for it's simplicity and because it is easy to learn the software.

Comment: a good item for the list